# Radius of convergence of the hyperbolic secant about the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate the radius of convergence of $\operatorname{sech}z$ about the origin?

I know its Maclaurin expansion and the formula for the radius of convergence:
$$\operatorname{sech}z =1-z^2+\frac5{24}z^4+\dots$$
…but what do?

Answer (score 0):

The radius of convergence will be the distance from the center of expansion ($0$) to the nearest pole ($\pi i/2$), so it is $\pi/2$.